# Do we know if RHEB is more sensitive to some amino acids than other amino acids?

Tags: senescence

RHEB (Ras homolog enriched in brain) senses amino acid levels in order to recruit mTOR. 
See [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21157483) review describing the process of how RHEB recruits mTOR. So does RHEB have differential selectivity towards different amino acids.

We also discussed this in Matt Kaeberlein's class yesterday and I posed this question but no one could answer it (that said, Matt Kaeberlein called it a good question).

Comment: Might be a good question in the context of your class, but that doesn't make it a good question for this forum since it does not provide any of the necessary context to readers.

Answer (score 2):

RHEB does not sense amino acids. See the abstract of [this](http://www.nature.com/onc/journal/v25/n5/full/1209106a.html) paper.

> Activation of this pathway requires inhibition of the tumor suppressor
>   complex TSC1/2. TSC2 is a GTPase-activating protein for the small
>   GTPase Ras homologue enriched in brain (Rheb), GTP loading of which
>   activates mTOR by a yet unidentified mechanism. The level at which
>   this pathway senses the availability of amino acids is unknown but is
>   suggested to be at the level of TSC2. Here, we show that amino-acid
>   depletion completely blocks insulin- and TPA-induced Rheb activation.
>   **This indicates that amino-acid sensing occurs upstream of Rheb.**
>   Despite this, amino-acid depletion can still inhibit mTOR/S6 kinase
>   signaling in TSC2-/- fibroblasts. Since under these conditions
>   Rheb-GTP levels remain high, a second level of amino-acid sensing
>   exists, affecting mTOR activity in a Rheb-independent fashion.

RHEB also doesn't have any [amino-acid binding](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q921J2) (or any small molecule binding) domain.